# SQL Server - Get approximate size of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In production, issuing a `SELECT COUNT` can be a bad idea - it can be a performance hit depending on your database engine. In Oracle, if I want to get an idea of the size of a table without having to resort to a `COUNT`, I can do the following:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    num_rows,
    last_analyzed
FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME';
```

This will retrieve Oracle's table analyses if they're enabled. While the count isn't exact, it can give me an idea of how large a table is in case I need to query it (and the last_analyzed column lets me know how old that approximation is).

How can I do something similar in SQL Server? (Related - is this necessary for SQL Server? Oracle has to count row-by-row, hence the avoidance.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the management studio also

```
Right Click on table -> Properties -> Storage
```

or you can use the query like this:

```
sp_spaceused 'TableName'
```

To get it for all the tables you can use it like tihs:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    tableName varchar(100),
    numberofRows varchar(100),
    reservedSize varchar(50),
    dataSize varchar(50),
    indexSize varchar(50),
    unusedSize varchar(50)
)
insert #tmp
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @cmd="EXEC sp_spaceused '?'"


select  * from #tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `sp_spaceused 'table_name'`.

If you want to do this for all tables, wrap it inside `sp_MSforeachtable`:

```
sp_MSforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''[?]'''
```

Calling `sp_spaceused` without any parameter will give you the database size.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy: [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896564/get-table-and-index-storage-size-in-sql-server)

```
SELECT 
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'    -- filter out system tables for diagramming
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    s.Name, t.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If absolute accuracy isn't vital this is a very quick route to an approximate row count; if your SQL Server is a supported version it should have this dmv.

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('MY_TABLE_NAME')   
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```