# Sql Server 2016 - Create Index script make database grow indefinitely

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

We have a Sql Server 2008 R2 SP3 we wanted to change for a 2016 SP1 Version. In addition of that, we needed to create some indexes (nonclustered).

When we executed the script in the Sql Server 2008 version, we had no problem at all, even if the script took 2 hours to complete (we have 2 big tables with dozen of millions of lines impacted by those indexes), it did create effectively the indexes.

When we tried to execute the script in the Sql Server 2016 version, the database mdf file grew until it filled the entire disk space. Even when we specified "SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON" with a tempdb located in a different disk (with 260 Gb of space...), the tempdb grew until it stopped after a few minutes (not even filling the disk full space !) and, it's the main database which was impacted again, filling again the disk full space...

Why this difference between Sql Server 2008 and Sql Server 2016 ? It's the same data, the same script, and, yet, the 2016 version consume a lot of space only to create those indexes...

Is anyone encountered the same behavior ?

Thanks !

Comment: I suggest also checking out https://dba.stackexchange.com which might be more targeted for this

Comment: Yeah sorry, I searched (badly) indeed the right place to post my question, I didn't see this dba.stackexchange.com room. Do I need to move my question ?

Comment: can you try to create two small test tables (with same schema and same data and 1 million rows) in 2008r2 and 2016 and check the space used by indexes,you [can use this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896564/get-table-and-index-storage-size-in-sql-server) to get table and space usage sqlserver

Comment: After doing that update your question with the table schema and index creation scripts you created and the size in both.This is the only way one can answer the question provided they have 2008r2